# SQL Server Management Studio: Return Rows in View1 that Don't Join View2

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, view

I am using the following script to join two views so that I can count the # of row events fall from view2 fall into view1. However, I would also like to see the row events in view1 that DON'T have any view2 row events under it.

Script:

```
Select vp.id, vp.EventName, vp.Unit, vp.Product, vp.StartTime, vp.EndTime, vp.Production, vp.BDP,  count(distinct vl.Name) as NumLCs 
from [V_ProductionEvents] vp 
join [V_LossEvents] vl on vl.Unit = vp.Unit and vl.StartTime >= vp.StartTime and vl.EndTime <= vp.EndTime
where  vp.StartTime > '2/01/2017'
group by vp.id, vp.Unit, vp.StartTime, vp.EndTime, vp.EventName, vp.Product, vp.bdp, vp.Production
order by vp.StartTime desc
```

For every Loss event that is within the Production Event start/end time, NumLC +=1... Does anyone know how I can view more production events that have 0 "NumLCs"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SSMS

Comment: Use a left join instead of an inner join, and check if the right side is null, e.g. `select * from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.fk_id where t2.fk_id is null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `left join`:

```
select 
    vp.id
  , vp.EventName
  , vp.Unit
  , vp.Product
  , vp.StartTime
  , vp.EndTime
  , vp.Production
  , vp.BDP
  , NumLCs = count(distinct vl.Name)
from [V_ProductionEvents] vp 
  left join [V_LossEvents] vl 
     on vl.Unit = vp.Unit 
    and vl.StartTime >= vp.StartTime 
    and vl.EndTime   <= vp.EndTime
where vp.StartTime > '2/01/2017'
group by 
    vp.id
  , vp.Unit
  , vp.StartTime
  , vp.EndTime
  , vp.EventName
  , vp.Product
  , vp.bdp
  , vp.Production
order by vp.StartTime desc
```